# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.myApp.data.entities.User

Tags: java, hibernate, mysql-connector

I have gone through most of the similar issues posted here and the solution found there was to use javax.persistence.Entity import instead of org.hibernate.annotations.Entity.

I have used the correct import but still getting `org.hibernate.MappingException`

I am using mysql-connector-java version 6.0.5 with hibernate-core version 5.2.6.Final and hibernate-annotations version 3.5.6-Final

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.myApp.data.entities.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.myApp.data.Application.main(Application.java:26)
```

The pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-course</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hibernate-course</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The following is my main class Application.java

```
package com.myApp.data;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.myApp.data.entities.User;


public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        User user = new User();
        user.setBirthDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedBy("Smith");
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        user.setEmailAddress("david_cfd@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("David");
        user.setLastName("Copperfield");
        user.setLastUpdatedBy("david");
        user.setLastUpdatedDate(new Date());

        session.save(user);

        session.close();
    }
}
```

User Entity class

```
package com.myApp.data.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="finances_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

}
```

Hibernate SessionFactory Configuration class

```
package com.myApp.data;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            return configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                            .build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "There was an error building the factory");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and finally hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">infinite</property>
        <property name="connection.password">skills</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.myApp.data.entities.User"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I checked the same thing using hibernate.properties instead of hibernate.cfg.xml by using `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);` and It compiled and executed with out any exception.

Comment: I would like to take a look at this method: configuration.configure(); inside your HibernateUtil

Comment: No this is not the JPA API. Tags fixed!

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I used configuration.configure(); to set hibernate.cfg.xml as default configuration as I also have a hibernate.properties file inside my resources

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry I didnt understand what you were trying to say. Could you please explain? And I know I am using hibernate API, if  you are indeed pointing out the use of import javax.persistence.Entity; instead of org.hibernate.annotations, itz because org.hibernate.annotations is deprecated and existed before JPA 1.

Comment: Could you verify what happens if you use the no-arg buildSessionFactory()? Your mapping class declaration looks correct.

Comment: @MattC it executes without any exception when i am using no arg buildSessionFactory(). I dont understand why it acts like that. Are you not supposed to pass a serviceregistry as parameter to buildSessionFactory? It also worked the same when i used hibernate.properties instead of xml file which was already working before changing it to no-arg buildSessionFactory. Can somebody please explain why this happened?

Comment: @MattC Thankyou it solved the problem, though I dont understand how it works. Please help me with this

Comment: You tagged your question as `jpa`. That is for questions that are using the JPA API. Consequently I removed the tag, so I posted the comment as advice to you not to tag such questions as jpa

Comment: @NeilStockton I am sorry, I only specified JPA among the tags, hoping that someone with knowledge in JPA could also solve this, after all Hibernate follows JPA specs. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @MattC I thought buildSessionFactory() was depricated since hibernate 4.3.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. The above code will work fine in **Hibernate 4.3.6** but problem is when working with **Hibernate 5**. The problem is with the following code:

```
    return configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build());
```

The problem is when you pass the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder as an argument inside buildSessionFactory(). When you do this the configuration loose all mapping information that is acquired through `configuration.configure();` statement.

That is why the code worked fine when using **hibernate.properties** file (which doesnt use configuration.configure() ) but caused an exception when using **hibernate.cfg.xml**.

**When using hibernate.cfg.xml**

When using hibernate xml configuration method, you can simply return the `sessionFactory` that uses a `no-arg` `buildSessionFactory()` method.

The actual code the works (using **hibernate.cfg.xml**)

Issue solved!

```
package com.myApp.data;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.myApp.data.entities.User;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            /*return configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                            .build());  -- does not work while using hibernate.cfg.xml, but works with hibernate.properties*/

            return configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "There was an error building the factory");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    }
```

Thanks for all who helped!

Comment: @MattC you saved my day!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. When in doubt, I try to simplify and try different variations.

Answer (score 0):

try using AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration.

```
Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
```

Comment: This results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Mappings exception